# Does "use strict" in the first line of a file affect all the functions in the file?

Tags: typescript, tslint

So I have this code adapted from [here](http://www.davidmclifton.com/2011/07/22/simple-telnet-server-in-node-js/) for learning purposes:

```
"use strict";
/// <reference path="./definitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts" />
import * as net from "net";

let sockets: net.Socket[] = [];

/*
 * Cleans the input of carriage return, newline
 */
function cleanInput(data: Buffer): string {
    return data.toString().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
}

/*
 * Method executed when data is received from a socket
 */
function receiveData(socket: net.Socket, data: Buffer): void {
    let cleanData: string = cleanInput(data);
    if (cleanData === "@quit") {
        socket.end("Goodbye!\r\n");
    } else {
        for (var i: number = 0; i < sockets.length; i++) {
            if (sockets[i] !== socket) {
                sockets[i].write(data);
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Method executed when a socket ends
 */
function closeSocket(socket: net.Socket): void {
    let i: number = sockets.indexOf(socket);
    if (i !== -1) {
        sockets.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

/*
 * Callback method executed when a new TCP socket is opened.
 */
function newSocket(socket: net.Socket): void {
    sockets.push(socket);
    socket.write("Welcome to the Telnet server!\r\n");
    socket.on("data", function(data: Buffer): void {
        receiveData(socket, data);
    });
    socket.on("end", function(): void {
        closeSocket(socket);
    });
}

// create a new server and provide a callback for when a connection occurs
let server: net.Server = net.createServer(newSocket);

// listen on port 4444
server.listen(4444);
console.log("started");
```

I'm running [tslint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint) on this file with these [tslint.json](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/docs/sample.tslint.json) rules.

This is what I'm getting:

> app.ts[10, 1]: missing 'use strict'
>
> app.ts[17, 1]: missing 'use strict'
>
> app.ts[33, 1]: missing 'use strict'
>
> app.ts[43, 1]: missing 'use strict'

My understanding, is that `"use string";`  on the first line of the file should be global across the whole file. Yet, each of the functions yields a message. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding, is that "use string"; on the first line of the file should be global across the whole file. Yet, each of the functions yields a message

Your understanding is correct. However you requested tslint to ensure it for all *functions* as well with `"check-function"` [set to true](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/6034a4b04cc02fdcb6dda70b358b62d921544259/docs/sample.tslint.json#L84). Set it to false as it's not needed if you have enabled for module level.

Comment: In other words the defaults in this sample file do not make practical sense?

Comment: One reason for enabling it for both levels is to allow safety in concatenation. See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Strict_mode_for_scripts

Comment: I wonder if typescript has special handling of those for concatenation. The compiler has the option to bundle everything into a single file, so it would be logical if they have considered that

Comment: you'd be surprised : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Comment: omg! Atom, huh? Need to try Atom again... must have matured by now. As for concatenation, what particular scenario would be improved if you have them both on? For concatenation purposes as far as I can see *your code* need to have strict functions on strict files off and then it seems to be safe for concatenation. With them both on you still have problem if the *other code* rely on not being strict.

Answer (score 1):

Strict mode can be enabled on both, the global scope or within single functions:

```
// Enable strict mode globally
"use strict";
var v = "This script is in strict mode.";
```

Or locally:

```
function strict() {
  'use strict';

  function nested() {
    return "Nested function is also in strict mode.";
  }

  return "Function is in strict mode. " + nested();
}

function notStrict() {
  return "This function is not in strict mode.";
}
```